# Bulk Update Tags in SharePoint Picture Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Our Marketing department would like a way to tag and search (perhaps a couple thousand) images.

IT is moving everyone away from file shares, and we have a bunch of free space in SharePoint; so that is looking like a good option, but I am running into some problems.

I have created a Picture Library and uploaded some pictures to test with. I've added a Managed Metadata column for the tags.

The issue is that Marketing would like to be able to bulk tag photos with existing tags, and to have those tags added rather than overwriting the existing tags.

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.konverge.com/blog/adding-metadata-multiple-documents-sharepoint/), which seems like it would get me exactly what I need, but I am not able to select a range of records to tag, and I am not getting the "Add these terms to all selected fields" option. Instead of "Quick Edit" I only have "Edit in grid view". Otherwise, the screenshots in the tutorial make it look like I'm on the same version of SharePoint. I'm using SharePoint Online.

The screenshot below is from the tutorial. I do not get the options in the first image, but I get the very same screen as in the second image.

[Screenshot from Tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1BCn.png)